# How to rename an item in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I want the user to be able to directly rename an item in a ListBox with the same effect as we can see in the file explorer of Windows by example. Like this:
[image]

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: A TextBox in the ItemTemplate? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: My items are a from a custom class I made myself so I wonder if there is a different way of doing it than changing the type of my items.

Comment: Why would you have to "*change the type*"? Just bind the TextBox.Text property to the displayed property of the item class. Keep in mind that we can't magically see your code. We only know the things you show us.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea but how do you realize that? I just have a `<ListBox x:Name="ListBox">` and in the code something like that `ListBox.ItemsSource = _list`. I'm new to WPF and the concept of binding is still a quite strange to me.

Comment: What contains your `_list`? Is there TextBox control, through which you able to edit its content?

Comment: `_list` contains items from a custom class I made with various attributes. I overrided the ToString method to get a simple string which is shown in the ListBox. I don't know where to put the TextBox. In an ItemTemplate as Bender said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your item class has a read/write property that is displayed in the ListBox, e.g.

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

you could bind the Text property of a TextBox in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox to that property:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In order to have the ItemText property updated while you type into the TextBox (in contrast to when the TextBox loses focus), you would have to set the Binding's UpdateSourceTrigger:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how the Binding method knows that ItemText come from a MyItem object ?

Comment: Because you have assigned a collection of MyItem to the ItemsSource property. The Binding finds the property by [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).